# Redirect graphical output to multi-page PDF in Julia

Tags: pdf-generation, julia

I would like to redicrect all graphical output from a Julia Language script into a single multipage PDF file, similar to what would be in R:

```
pdf(foo.pdf) 
plot(dummy1) 
plot(dummy2)
... 
plot(dummyn)
dev.off()
```

Redicrecting the output stream through

```
writemime(io, "application/pdf", plot)
```

works for a single file, but it somehow doesn't seem to append to an existing file.

Note that I'd just like to have all figures from a script into a single pdf. I do not want to do extensive reporting through weave.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there a pressing need to do this exclusively via julia? If you produce the pdf images as separate pdfs, you can then just run one of the many excellent unix system commands for joining pdfs.

Comment: I'd like to be able to run the same code on a unix server and a windows VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use matplotlib's PdfPages backend which I guess is a bit of a cheat answer as its using python but here's an example anyway.

e.g.

```
using PyCall, PyPlot
@pyimport matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf as pdf

figures = [] # this array will contain all of the figures
for i in 1:2
    f = figure(figsize=(11.69,8.27)) # A4 figure
    ax = subplot(111)
    ax[:plot](rand(5,100)) # random plot
    push!(figures,f) # add figure to figures array
end

pdffile = pdf.PdfPages("fig.pdf") # create pdf file
[pdffile[:savefig](f) for f in figures] # add figures to file
pdffile[:close]() # close pdf file
```

Comment: Remark: when I run the commands as below, with plot generation in the same script, it finishes perfectly. However, when I generate the figures as `Plots.Plot{Plots.PyPlotBackend}` objects resulting from a function call, the first plot in the iteration will just be a straight line and all the other ones will be correct. I currently work around this by plotting the first one twice, and then writing `[pdffile[:savefig](f) for f in figures[1:4]]` into the pdf. Works, but I'd like to understand why this occurs.

Comment: Not sure sorry I haven't got round to using the Plots.jl interface yet.